# htaccess https redirect for http requests fails on subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I've been having this problem with htaccess... I didn't learn it from scratch so I'm always fooling around a bit.. Although I would like to learn it properly as well, if anyone knows a good place, let me know as well..

So but my thing is.. Is that I want to have all non HTTPS requests redirected to the https version and that if a page shouldn't be working because of a trailing slash missing it would add it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://webshirts.eu/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css|js|svg|png|pdf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://webshirts.eu/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Right below there's a link to a sub folder on which it fails, this site domain is purely for testing and doesn't have a certificate. The real one does though.
https://webshirts.eu/test/

So the thing is that this doesn't work.. and I can't exactly find out why.. It worked without the top part of https !on, like perfectly, only I need to redirect the request url '/' to https.. The rest of the site always includes links to https.. So after that its gone to https, it's never going out of it.

Any help would be appreciated :) 
Thanks!
Cheers!

Nikolai

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Entering `http://webshirts.eu/test/` correctly forwards to `https://webshirts.eu/test/` and entering `http://webshirts.eu` correctly redirects to `https://webshirts.eu`

Comment: Guys thanks!! I'm gonna get back to this soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code to try if it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   #RewriteRule (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Guys thanks!! I'm gonna get back to this soon as I can!